# Сложно отметить участника с телефона в комментарии на мете

Tags: обсуждение, поддержка, комментарии, мобильная-версия

С компьютера все ясно, там нет сложностей, но вот с телефона, это какое "игра-а ну ка попробуй", порой идет во все стороны, на ссылку какую-то клик идет или еще выходит из страницы☹️(*видно, что я тыкаю/кликаю на ник)

Вообщем-то на мете крайне не удобно и достаточно сложно отметить участника, чтоб ответить на комментарий.

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На основном сайте совсем не так, и сразу после вывода собачки, одно прикосновение выводит никНейм

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

У всех также, или может есть "лайфхак"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Это поведение работает одинаково, что на Мете, что на основном сайте. После ввода собачки `@` в поле комментария, подсказка появляется для **нелатинских** никнеймов, которых можно пингануть в текущем комментарии. Это сделано для устранения возможной проблемы ввода, когда у отвечающего в комментариях просто-напросто нет соответствующей клавиатурной раскладки.

Проблема с кликом/тапом на мобильном устройстве по имени присутствует, но причина эта обусловлена просто достаточно малой площадью экрана для взаимодействия, что увеличивает шанс кликнуть/тапнуть не туда, а на что-то расположенное рядом или на уровне ниже (на фоне). Такая проблема есть на Android (наверное, можно её решить альтернативными клавиатурами). На клавиатуре Apple iPad, например, есть кнопка <kbd>Tab</kbd>, которая упрощает выбор никнейма после ввода `@`.

Comment: Если это связано с телефоном, то почему на основном сайте, всегда легко, а здесь всегда сложно. В вёрстках есть разница в площади? (маленькая /большая)

Comment: @Dev18 я не замечал различий в этом поведении м/у Метой и основным сайтом.

Comment: Я когда пытаюсь выбрать никнейм с телефона, вечно тыкаю на флажок, что очень бесит. Иной раз это превращается в лютый пиксель-хантер на пару минут.

Comment: @Amgarak оформил [пост](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/396815/339911) на MSE.